# DatePicker UI Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

I have been trying to use a `DatePicker` but there is a strange problem in the UI rendering of it.

Below is the screen shot of the UI:

[image: Below is the screen shot of UI]

Whereas I want it like below:

[image: Expected]

Has anyone seen this before? How can I solve it?

Below is the XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
  <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/dpResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the code,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the full calendar view and just want to see the spinners on the date picker, use the [calendarViewShown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#attr_android%3acalendarViewShown) attribute and set it to false. If the DatePicker is still oddly rendered, it might indicate that you have set some unnecessary attributes in the app's theme.

Comment: To expand on this, the second image in the question is the old style DatePicker, which I believe is for SDK level <11. Note that [Simon Vig Therkildsen has also backported the new one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-datepicker) to Android 2.2.